# Validating motor control architecture using Raspberry Pi hardware PWM

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, actuator, motordriver

I need a validation that what I am doing is correct. Please look at the part of schematic shown below.

I am driving two linear actuators through Raspberry Pi 4b. Both enable pins of each motor driver input is connected to hardware PWM on gpio(). I am driving the actuators at 8 KHz PWM frequency. All is working fine, I am able to control and drive the actuators at minimum 55% speed by changing duty cycle on the motor enable pin of the motor driver.

Is there a risk in controlling the actuators using this configuration? Is there a possibility that noise or vibration can damage the actuator or motor driver? I have seen one actuator getting damaged and one motor driver circuit not working out of 15 batch. I am trying to link if it is happening because of this configuration or PWM frequency or it might be something else.

Motor inputs are coming from rpi which is 3.3v, so to do level shifting we pass it through 74HC244 IC which converts into 5v logic and giving it to motor driver circuit.
My question is simple, I need to validate that my current configuration to add pwm on INh pin is safe to control the speed of actuators

[image]

Comment: Could you _edit your question_ to mention the purpose of U4?  For that matter, adding a paragraph or two of your circuit theory-of-operation  would not be a bad thing.